# change speed of an array loop? Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, arrays, nslog

I have this code

```
NSArray *food = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Apples:",@"bacon",@"corn",@"donuts",@"elfs",@"fidge",nil];

for(int i = 0; i<6; i++){
    NSLog(@"item at index %i is %@",i,[food objectAtIndex:i]);

}
```

and right now they are all printed to the console instantly. How can I make a variable to decrease or increase the speed they are logged?
I'm new at objective-C so thanks a lot for your help! :)

Comment: I don't understand, you want to slow down the loop? You could sleep between each cycle. But why?

Comment: yeah, how can I sleep between each cycle? I also want to change how long it would sleep.

Comment: What problem are you really trying to solve?

Comment: lol. I want a program that will NSLog different words from an array with an input time separation. Sorry I just dont know the right questions to ask how to do this.

for example. using an array "One Two Three Four" I would like to have "One" printed to the screen, then a second later "Two", ...

I would also like to be able to change the length of time that is waited in between words

Answer (score 2):

```
NSArray *food = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Apples:",@"bacon",@"corn",@"donuts",@"elfs",@"fidge",nil];

// the number of seconds to wait between printing each item
double secondsToSleep = 1.0;

for(int i = 0; i<6; i++){
    [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:secondsToSleep];
    NSLog(@"item at index %i is %@",i,[food objectAtIndex:i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a sleepForTimeInterval: method on NSThread that might do what you're looking for. The documentation is [here](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSThread_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSThread/sleepForTimeInterval:).

**Edit:** Sorry, for Objective-C newbies, you would just type something like this:

```
[NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:0.01];
```

Comment: I tried using this technique for a progress bar and it seems it sleeps first then executes the loop, so its really no slower.

Answer (score 0):

See the `sleep()` function.